# Akka: pipeto self and parent

Tags: scala, akka

In my actor I have this sequence of messages:

```
var sndr: ActorRef = _

override def receive: Receive = {
      case msg @ Message => 
          sndr = sender
          HttpRequest.singleRequest(...) pipeTo self

      case smt @ HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, _, entity1, _) => sndr ! SomethingElse(smt)

}
```

I am saving the original "sender" in a variable. Is this the best way to send the final message to the original sender (as with the `Something` message it becomes the `self`)?

Comment: To all readers: any answer below that mentions `forward` is wrong because the original sender is lost already at the `pipeTo` step.

Comment: This is the official documentation: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/http/client-side/request-level.html and `pipeTo` it is `Future` itself. But it is considered bad practice using own defined Futures insider actors. It is a sort of catch22

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't keep the sender in a variable. What if there are multiple messages from different callers before the first one is complete? Only the last one would be routed correctly. Try this:

```
override def receive: Receive = {
  case msg @ Message => 
      HttpRequest.singleRequest(...).map(SomethingElse(_)) pipeTo sender
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `SomethingElse(_)` take place on a different thread and is not safe?

Comment: @carbon_ghost I am assuming `SomethingElse` is a case class (immutable) which is the typical pattern when working with actor messages.